# The proof of Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, absolute-convergence

Studying Analysis with 'Principles of Mathematical Analysis Third edition' written by Walter Rudin, I got some trouble from the proof of Taylor's theorem.

The theorem and the proof from the book are these:
Theorem: 
Suppose $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n,$$ the series converging in $|x|<R$. If $-R<a<R$, then $f$ can be expanded in a power series about the point $x=a$ which converges in $|x-a|<R-|a|$, and 
$$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n \quad (|x-a|<R-|a|).$$

Proof.
We have
$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n[(x-a)+a]^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} a^{n-m}(x-a)^m\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty \binom{n}{m} c_n a^{n-m}(x-a)^{m},
\end{align*}$
and the equation is permissible if
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n |c_n\binom{n}{m} a^{n-m}(x-a)^m|$$
converges, which is the same as 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n|(|x-a|+|a|)^n,$$
converging if $|x-a|+|a|<R.$

What I wonder is, if $\{c_n\}$ converges but not absolutely, for example
$$c_n = (-1)^n\frac{1}{n},$$
isn't it troublesome convincing
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n|(|x-a|+|a|)^n$$
converges if $|x-a|+|a|<R$?

Comment: http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/taylorscontents.html

Comment: In your example, $R=1$, and there is no trouble seeing that series converges when $|x-a|+|a|<1$.